# Bad file descriptor error in Output redirection in c

Tags: c

I'm making a simple shell using c and when trying to redirect the output to a file, I cannot open that file or view its content to make sure my redirection actually worked, that is after exiting the simple shell and returning to the "actual" shell. I get Output.txt: Permission denied

Does anyone know what is happening? Here is part of my code

Note that redir is 1 when in args[] we have '>'.

```
   while(1) {
    
    bg = 0;
    int cnt = getcmd("\n>> ", args, &bg);

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) {

        if (redir == 1) {
            int stdout = dup(1);
            close(1);
            int fd = open(args[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU);      
            dup2(fd,1);
            redir = 0;
        }
        
        if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0) { 
            printf("exec failed\n");
            exit(1); 
        }
        exit(0);
    }  
    else if (pid == -1){      
        printf("ERROR: fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
   }
```

Comment: `>`, like its target, doesn't go in args. It's an instruction to a shell to run `dup2()` to overwrite stdout with a file handle on the desired output file after the fork and before the exec. It isn't passed to the program being run, but is consumed by the shell before that program starts.

Comment: Also, don't use the `bash` tag if you aren't asking about the bash language or _specifically_ the bash shell implementation (as opposed to other shells or shells in general).

Comment: As for the permission error... (1) what's the active umask? (2) which operating sytem are you on? (Windows in particular only lets one program have a write handle on a given file at a given time by default, for compatibility with software written for the ancient FAT filesystem's limitations).

Comment: Im on windows but im using a remote linux server. I changed some things in my code and it works now. Just gotta figure out my nothing is redirected to that file

Comment: Have you updated your code to use `dup2` to overwrite file descriptor 1 before the exec call?

Comment: yeah i updated my code to this: if (redir == 1) {
    int stdout = dup(1);
    close(1);
    int fd = open(args[2], O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRWXU);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    redir = 0;
   }

Comment: sorry if this is not really readable but after using dup2 it gives me bad file descriptor error

Comment: I don't see you closing the original fd. Also, since there are no answers to worry about invalidating, your can and should edit the question rather than leaving essential information only in comments.

Comment: Why are you backing up the original stdout? The parent process is still using it, so it's not like it needs to be restored.

Comment: Im still new, I dont really see where I can edit this post. Also, so what youre saying is that I need to close(fd) after dup2(fd, 1) ? But doing that still gives me a bad file descriptor error

Comment: Which _specific_ call gives you that error? Use the [edit] link to add details to the question.

Comment: dup2(fd,1) gives me that error. I believe I need to restore stdout but if I restore it with dup2(stdout, 1), nothing gets redirected and written in the output file

Comment: Why would you need to restore stdout? You're in a child process. It doesn't need to know what stdout would have been if there _hadn't_ been a redirection; it just needs to know what its stdout _actually is_. The shell supports restores but that's because it has subshells, builtins, and other cases where it exits a section of code that was redirected _without_ terminating that section with an `execv`-family function, but right now you're not dealing with them.

Comment: `dup2` throwing EBADF implies that `fd` wasn't valid. Make sure you checked for errors after the `open()`.

Comment: BTW, personally, I'd skip the `close()`. Just overwriting the old FD should do.

Comment: ive tested my code and my fd = 1 which is correct since I closed stdout, but for some reason my redir is always 1 and it appears that redir = 0; does not work. I believe this is causing the bad file descriptor error but i dont really know what could be causing this.

Comment: Personally, I'd skip the explicit close (so `open()` _can't_ assign FD 1 immediately) and do the `dup2()` unconditionally; one less source of things that can differ between invocations.

Comment: and then use close(fd) after the dup2(fd,1) ? But I dont know how without doing close(1) the redirection would be completed.